# Unable to delete standard user account

Tags: user-account, macos

I have an administration acct and a standard acct in my computer. I go to delete the standard but, after unlocking the lock, it does not allow me to select the standard, only the adm. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What os? Answers will vary

Answer (score 1):

If that account is logged through fast user switching, log it out first. If that isn't the case, well, there could be many potential solutions but one that has worked in many of the cases I've seen is to create a 3rd account, an administrator, and try to delete the standard user using this 3rd account.